# CSS in the Browser crashes if it needs to show more than 80 records

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My task is to show records in the table format. The records can be populated either from uploaded Excel file, or from Database. The report in the table format works well as long as the number of records to be shown are 70 or less. But, for us, sometimes we may need to show upto 2000 records.
When the records count reaches more than 80, the CSS styles get crashed and web page looks ugly. In general, we upload Excel files with size upto 100kb (max), but not more than that. When debugged the code, found that code is working well, but just CSS crashes and web page looks ugly.

When searched in Google, I'm getting answers which are related to uploading large files, but not for my issue.

Can someone please identify and resolve the issue!

Below is the code to retrieve data from either uploaded Excel file, or from database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(EligibilityIssuesViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.ExportedExcelFile != null)
                {
                    var folder = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploaded_excel_files");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                    }
                    var incomingFileName = model.ExportedExcelFile.FileName;
                    model.UploadedExcelFileName = Path.Combine(folder, incomingFileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(model.UploadedExcelFileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        model.ExportedExcelFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Flush();
                    }
                    model.HoldReasons = _bll.GetHoldReasons(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Retrieve HoldReason from Database
                    model.HoldReasons = _bll.GetHoldReasonsFromDB();
                }
                //return RedirectToAction("ProcessHoldReasons", "EligibilityIssues", new { model = model });
                TempData["HoldReasons"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.HoldReasons);
                return View(model);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = new HtmlString(@"Unexpected error occurred. Below is the message for your verification:<br />"
                + ex.Message);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Below is the View markup to show the populated data in html table format.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.HoldReasons != null)
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Hold Reasons</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var holdReason in Model.HoldReasons)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@holdReason.HoldReasonShouldBeChecked" />
                        <sapn>(@holdReason.InsType)</sapn>@holdReason.HoldReason
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" asp-action="ProcessHoldReasons" value="Process Hold Reasons" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Comment: You could consider adding paging for this table to avoid CSS crash. As you know no one could check more than 80 rows at same time.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: We've fundamental reason behind not selecting pagination. It was the constraint from our senior Business Analyst.

Comment: Could you please tell me which browser you have used ? Edge or else?

Comment: @BrandoZhang: I'm using Chrome browser. But, the application should be browser agnostic.